# How to check firewall for for specific endpoints on linux, using Command line?

Tags: networking, security, firewall

I'm looking to install a monitoring agent on a linux machine, and want to check for its [prereqs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-analytics-agent#firewall-requirements). The agent requires the following endpoints to be allowed by firewall team. How can I check to see if they are open, from my machine and *thereby show it to firewall team*, so that they can open them, if they are currently not open? Following are the endpoints:

```
 Agent Resource              Ports           Direction        Bypass HTTPS inspection
*.ods.opinsights.azure.com  Port 443    Inbound and Outbound    Yes
*.oms.opinsights.azure.com  Port 443    Inbound and Outbound    Yes
*.blob.core.windows.net     Port 443    Inbound and Outbound    Yes
*.azure-automation.net      Port 443    Inbound and Outbound    Yes
*.azure.com                 Port 443    Inbound and Outbound    Yes
```

- If so, does your solution also verify the Bypass HTTPS inspection?
  How?
- And does `OMS*.azure.com` come under the endpoint `*.azure.com`?

*`nc` not available*

TIA

Comment: Sorry I did not ask earlier. Is this for incoming or outgoing connections?

Comment: Both inbound and outbound.And its described in the question, if you are viewing the question on mobile phone, you'll have to scroll the screen to left to see those columns.

Comment: What will you be monitoring?

Comment: This is firewall requirement for Microsoft Azure Log Analytics Agent, it collects syslogs and perf counters data and push to Azure.

Comment: I've also added hyperlink to the monitoring agent page to prereqs in question

Comment: The document is not clear. It looks like it needs outgoing port 443 (no proxying or proxying that dose not break it). I can not see any intermediate steps to testing these outbound connections (unless you have some control over the remote servers, or can packer snoop just outside of your network).